# Need assistance creating a photo-button that serves as a link

Tags: html, razor

I am trying to make a large photo that when you hover over it enlarges and it also serves as a button that links to another HTML page.

I have tried making it a button - which is much easier to customize to my liking with the background image, but I cannot get it to link.
I have also used an  tag - which links to the page correctly but is much harder to customize correctly.

```
<div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-4"\>
   <button class="grow-button1"\> Come Join in Class\</button\>
</div\>


.grow-button1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url('images/misclassphoto.jpg');
  height: 8em;
  width: 8em;
  }

.grow-button1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  }`
```

Comment: If you insist on using button, you could use javascript.. `<button class="grow-button1" onclick="window.location.href='your-link-here.html';">Come Join in Class</button>`

Comment: A button is not a link. A button should never be a link.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using button, you could use javascript, try this:

`<button class="grow-button1" onclick="window.location.href='your-link-here.html';">Come Join in Class</button>`

I think the anchor tag is better than button.

```
<div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-4">
  <a href="your-link-here.html">
    <div class="grow-button1">
      <span>Come Join in Class</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Customize the button using CSS as follows

```
.grow-button1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url('images/misclassphoto.jpg');
  height: 8em;
  width: 8em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grow-button1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.grow-button1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```